# How to write a data.frame to a yaml file in certain format in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data.frame:

```
 x<-data.frame(files=c("/a/b/c/p1_fastq.gz", "/a/b/c/p2_fastq.gz"), ids=c("p1", "p2"))
 x
               files ids
1 /a/b/c/p1_fastq.gz  p1
2 /a/b/c/p2_fastq.gz  p2
```

How to write it as a yaml file `test.yaml` such like:

```
-
  id: "p1"
  fastq: "/a/b/c/p1_fastq.gz"
-
  id: "p2"
  fastq: "/a/b/c/p2_fastq.gz"
```

I have tried the `yaml` package in R but it write as

```
files:
-/a/b/c/p1_fastq.gz
-/a/b/c/p2_fastq.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `cat` with `sprintf` to paste the elements and write it to a `file`

```
cat(with(x, sprintf('-\nid: "%s"\nfastq: "%s"\n', ids, files)),
        "\n", file = "test.yaml")
```

-output

[image]

Comment: That's elegant. Thanks

Comment: The json shown in the `test.yaml` image may not be compliant yaml, though I'm assuming that `yaml::read_yaml` provides a canonical validation of json structure.

Comment: @r2evans You meant the position of `-`?  I also thought so

Comment: The output doesn't match the OP. You may want to add spaces, when in a `-` list, no text should be in column 1 (though a yaml-dict does start with text in column 1).

Comment: How to remove the leading space started from the second "-"?

Answer (score 1):

@akrun's answer is great for base R. An alternative is to use the [`yaml`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/yaml/index.html) package to do things for you:

```r
library(yaml)
yaml <- as.yaml(mtcars[1:3, 1:3])
cat(yaml, "\n")
# mpg:
# - 21.0
# - 21.0
# - 22.8
# cyl:
# - 6.0
# - 6.0
# - 4.0
# disp:
# - 160.0
# - 160.0
# - 108.0
```

An alternative is to do row-major (aka "not column major"), where each list element represents a *row*:

```r
yaml <- as.yaml(mtcars[1:3, 1:3], column.major = FALSE)
cat(yaml, "\n")
# - mpg: 21.0
#   cyl: 6.0
#   disp: 160.0
# - mpg: 21.0
#   cyl: 6.0
#   disp: 160.0
# - mpg: 22.8
#   cyl: 4.0
#   disp: 108.0
```

though `yaml::as.yaml` recommends the first method (`column.major=TRUE`, the default).

With your data, one of

```r
cat(as.yaml(x), "\n")
# files:
# - /a/b/c/p1_fastq.gz
# - /a/b/c/p2_fastq.gz
# ids:
# - p1
# - p2
cat(as.yaml(x, column.major = FALSE), "\n")
# - files: /a/b/c/p1_fastq.gz
#   ids: p1
# - files: /a/b/c/p2_fastq.gz
#   ids: p2
```